# How to fix the pre-commit-msg in my git environment?

Tags: bash, git, sh, githooks, pre-commit

Has someone have experienced a weird behaviour of .git/hooks/pre-commit-msg?
The file has proper permission in being executed.
And actually it is executed. The issue is that the commits, any commits with correct or uncorrect messages, make the execution goes into the error.
Always.

The correct message should be something like these examples:

- "ABC-123/ticket-task blah blha"
- "ABC-234/ticket-task fixed some things"
- "ABC-123/ticket-task added some"

where the first word after [test], or [fix], or [feat] is chosen between a set (like Added, Fixed, Upgraded..)

Working on OSX, with git, with zsh shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
#

commit_message=$(cat .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG)
commit_error="Error in the commit message. Prefix with 
JIRA ticket. For example UXD-1234/git-hook"


if [[ ! $commit_message =~ /([A-Z]+[-][\d]+\/\S+)/  ]]; then
  echo >&2 $commit_error
  exit 1
fi
```

Is there an error in this code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think this is related to git at all, the problem seems to be in matching the regex: `if [[ ! 'ABC-123/something' =~ /([A-Z]+[-][\d]+\/\S+)/ ]]; then echo 'no match'; else echo 'match'; fi` has the output `no match`. Specifically it seems to be backslash escaping, as `if [[ ! 'ABC-123/something' =~ ^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+ ]]; then echo 'no match'; else echo 'match'; fi` *does* output `match`.

Comment: in this way, it is still possible to commit `UXD-12/` and this should be out. I tried with this `^[A-Z]+-[0-9][/]+` but this also is not working at all, I need to check also the slash and at least a character.

Comment: If you need *"also the slash and at least a character"* then maybe e.g. `^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+/[a-zA-Z]`? Or you'll need to work out how to handle backslashes (so you can use `\d` too). `[/]+` would be a character class containing a single character, the forward slash, repeated one or more times, which is both an unnecessary class and not what you're describing.

Comment: I managed to rewrite the regular expression this way: `[[ ABC-123/some =~ [A-Z]+-[0-9]+/[^\ ]+ ]] && echo yes || echo no` (result is `yes`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the correct answer

```
^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+/[a-zA-Z]
```

Thanks to @jonrsharpe